# UIWebView will load one URL but not another

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

I have the UIWebView set up fine in a custom Cell but having problems loading a custom url. I want to show a youtube video in full screen within the UIWebView, to do this in a browser you can Remove "watch?v=" and in its place put "v/" and then add "&index=18" to the end of the URL. This works fine in a browser but UIWebView doesn't seem to like it. I've tested the url being produced in the log and that works fine in browser but not in UIWebView.

ViewController.h

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController < UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIWebViewDelegate>

{
NSMutableArray *tableArray;

CGFloat screenWidth;
CGFloat screenHeight;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *listArray;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

GameChooserCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"GameChooserCell"];

//If the cell is nil it means no cell was available for reuse and that we should create a new one.

if (cell == nil) {

    // Actually create a new cell (with an identifier so that it can be dequeued).

    cell = [[GameChooserCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"GameChooserCell"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

}

/*
 *   Now that we have a cell we can configure it to display the data corresponding to
 *   this row/section
 */


cell.userNameLabel.text                = [[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:0];
cell.userNameLabel.textColor           = [UIColor grayColor];
cell.userNameLabel.layer.shadowColor   = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
cell.userNameLabel.layer.shadowOffset  = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
cell.userNameLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
cell.userNameLabel.layer.shadowRadius  = 1.0;


NSString *string = [[tableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:1];

string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"https" withString:@"http"];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"watch?v=" withString:@"v/"];
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&feature=youtube_gdata" withString:@""];
string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&index=18",string];

//string = @"http://www.google.com/images";

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];

NSLog(@"url = \"%@\"", url);

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[cell.webView loadRequest:request];
[cell.webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[cell.webView setOpaque:NO];
 cell.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;    /* Now that the cell is configured we return it to the table view so that it can display it */
cell.webView.delegate = self;

return cell;

 }

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview {
if (webview.isLoading)
    return;
}
```

If someone could shed some light on my problem that would be great.

Cheers Nick.

Comment: What is the value of `string` after the replacements?

Comment: NSLog is as follows  url = "https://www.youtube.com/v/9DoSqeJNG74%26index=18"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Add `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol
- Connect delegate `cell.webView.delegate = self;`

  `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview {
      if (webview.isLoading)
          return;
  }`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still no luck. I have no problems getting it to show a normal page, it's only when trying to show the edited youtube url.